# Executing multiple instances of iTMSTransporter

Tags: itunes, itmstransporter

Is it possible to execute parallel instances of iTMSTransporter. I'm executing the iTmsTransporter.cmd file with different parameters for different packages.

If I have two packages to be transported in parallel, one of them will be published while the other will fail with error saying "Cannot proceed with delivery: an existing transporter instance is currently uploading this package", In the upload error log I can see that it first gives an warning "Failed to obtain exclusive lock on token file.  Please ensure the following file is not locked by another process: C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile.itmstransporter\UploadTokens\_vendor_identifier.itmsp.token".

Unfortunately I don't have access to apple dev forums, so please if someone can put a light on it if we can upload packages in parallel using iTMSTransporter ?

Regards,
Haris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I've solved my problem, I guess the problem was that I was using same folder name for all the packages, I've observed that the .token file is created with the package folder name as a prefix. So when I made the package folder name unique per package, the transporter created multiple .token files for each of the transport, so no locking issue occurred this time. Earlier I thought the package folder name I was using is a special keyword and should be used as it is, which was a wrong assumption.

Regards,
Haris

Comment: You are right, al long as the package names are distinct, you should have no problem running multiple sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Historically this has not been a problem (I say historically because I have not used any of the 1.8 versions). I would make sure no instances are running, delete `_vendor_identifier.itmsp.token`, and try again.

I would also suggest using [The Transporter GUI](http://transportergui.com) (I am the author), it will improve your Transporter experience.

Comment: So if we have to delete an existing .token file, that means it can only be one instance at a time ? Can't use a GUI as the delivery process is automated through a windows service.